# How do I safely "eval" user code in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, security, eval, jslint

I'm working on a webapp to teach programming concepts.  Webpages have some text about a programming concept, then let the user type in javascript code into a text editor window to try to answer a programming problem.  When the user clicks "submit", I analyse the text they've typed to see if they have solved the problem.  For example, I ask them to "write a function named `f` that adds three to its argument".

Here's what I'm doing to analyse the user's text:

1. Run JSLint on the text with strict settings, in particular without assuming browser or console functions.
2. If there are any errors, show the errors and stop.
3. `eval(usertext);`
4. Loop through conditions for passing the assignment, `eval(condition)`.  An example condition is `"f(1)===4"`.  Conditions come from trusted source.
5. Show passing/failing conditions.

My questions: is this good enough to prevent security problems?  What else can I do to be paranoid?  Is there a better way to do what I want?

In case it is relevant my application is on Google App Engine with Python backend, uses JQuery, has individual user accounts.

Comment: I wonder if jsfiddle has any source/notes available... I am sure at some point it just comes down to the site not being vulnerable to XSS or similar. (XSS would *allow someone else* to give a link to code eval'ed on said page that may then "run as" the user who actually viewed the link.)

Comment: I have to say when I use JSLint to scan my JS for issues before compressing I try and disable every feature I can that simply represents the author's preference and not actually a code issue, then I disregard 90% of what it says and look for missing semi-colons and the like. If I were you I'd think about how much your users are going to enjoy reading the 'errors' JSLint finds.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll add an option to turn off the "stylistic" checks.  But I want the default to be strict, part of the point of the project is to teach clean javascript programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So from what I can tell if you are eval'ing a user's input only for them, this isn't a security problem. Only if their input is eval'd for *other* users you have a problem.

Eval'ing a user's input is no worse than them viewing source, looking at HTTP headers, using Firebug to inspect JavaScript objects, etc. They already have access to everything.

That being said if you do need to secure their code, check out Google Caja http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/

Comment: That's a good point.  If you have Firebug, you can eval anything you want.

Comment: I agree here.  It isn't a security problem for a user to be able to manipulate their own browser.  There are lots of ways to do that already (Firebug, GreaseMonkey, copy source and edit it, etc...).  It only becomes a security problem if any other user is ever able to execute the untrusted code in an environment that belongs to a different user than the one that created it without knowing what it might do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick question. There is no secure way to `eval()` user's code on your website.

Comment: Yes, but consider jsfiddle -- how can it be done "withing acceptable measures"?

Answer (score 2):

Not clear if the `eval()` occurs on client or server side. For client side:

- I think it's possible to eval safely in an well configured iframe (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/)
- This should be 100% safe, but needs a couple of libraries and has some limitations (no es6 support): https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter
- There are lighter alternatives but not 100% safe like https://github.com/commenthol/safer-eval.
- Alternatively, I think something similar can be implemented manually wrapping code in a with statement, overriding  `this`, globals and arguments. Although it will never be 100% safe maybe is viable in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done. Browsers offer no API to web pages to restrict what sort of code can be executed within a given context.

However, that might not matter. If you don't use any cookies whatsoever on your website, then executing arbitrary Javascript may not be a problem. After all, if there is no concept of authentication, then there's no problem with forging requests. Additionally, if you can confirm that the user *meant* to execute the script he/she sent, then you should also be protected from attackers, e.g., if you will only run script typed onto the page and never script submitted via GET or POST data, or if you include some kind of unique token with those requests to confirm that the request originated with your website.

Still, the answer to the *core* question is that it pretty much is that it can't be done, and that user input can never be trusted. Sorry :/

Comment: There is a concept of authentication, there are Google user accounts.  I don't know how they are implemented in GAE, but I'm guessing cookies store a session shared key or something.  Can you explain a bit more about distinguishing between typed scripts and GET POST requests?  How can I distinguish?

Comment: @Nathan: if the user types in the script on the page, it's safe to run, since we know the user meant to submit it. However, if the code comes from GET or POST data, then a malicious user can trick another user into sending that request, and running that script. (For GET, it's easy with a link. For POST, an auto-submitting form isn't that much harder.) Therefore, those requests shouldn't be allowed unless you can be sure they came from your site, meaning your site's forms need to include data that a malicious user couldn't have. Look up cross-site request forgery, and give users a secret token.

Comment: I don't think this statement is 100% true, you can eval in an iframe with sandbox="allow-scripts" as detailed here: (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) - But I agree on "never trusting user input" one.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest issue will always be preventing infinite loops for occurring in user-provided code. You may be able to hide "private" references by running `eval` in the right context, e.g.:

```
let userInput = getUserInput();
setTimeout(() => {
  let window = null;
  let global = null;
  let this = null;
  // ... set any additional references to `null`
  
  eval(userInput);
}, 0);
```

And you could wrap the above code in a `try/catch` to prevent syntax and logic errors from crashing outside of the controlled `eval` scope, but you will ([provably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) never be able to detect whether incoming user input defines an infinite loop that will tie up javascript's single thread, rendering its runtime context completely stalled. The only solution to a problem like this is to define your own javascript interpreter, use it to process the user's input, and provide a mechanism to limit the number of steps your javascript interpreter is willing to take. That would be a lot of trouble!